# Google Adsense Ads are not showing in Rails application

Tags: ads, adsense

I am created a website with Ruby on rails

Successfully added adsense code into my website template.

I was able to view the adsense ads in my local host for e.g. http://localhost:3000  but when I deployed the code into server the ads is empty. present using server ip ex: http://54.34.XXX.XX

I using Ruby On Rails . OS is Linux base.
I use passenger and Apache in server, deployed in aws

Anyone knows the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to verify your domain from ad-sense login panel